# Selection Formula Pass-through not working with SQL Command Object

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using Crystal Reports XI.  We use Crystal Reports embedded into a share point site written in C#/ASP.net.  Our web developers instatiate a report in code and pass the selection criteria by appending to the Select Formula object.

The problem I'm running in to is that when I use a SQL Command Object, the selection formula is not being passed to the sql server as a where clause.  This causes the entire result set to be queried and then limited on the server.  For very large tables, this is causing a significant performance hit.

Here's an example:
    SELECT foo.id, foo.code, foo.name
    FROM foo foo

Select criteria is shown as:
    {Command.name} like "someName"

If I then run the report the entire foo table is queried and then crystal reports limits from the entire set.

If instead I do it based on the table without a command object, the WHERE clause is appended to the sql query and all the limiting is done at the db level.

I'm assuming this occurs because a SQL command could potentially be very complex and adding a WHERE clause to the bottom isn't always possible.  My question then, is there any good way to force some sort of pass through.  Should I be talking to the C# devs and asking them to rework the way we pass parameters?

Thanks for any help and discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A record-selection formula is never added to the Command-object's query.

I'm not certain if the CR SDK supports Command object modification (I know it supports read-only access, however).

The Command object does support parameters (in 2008, they can be multi-valued parameters) which can be accessed programmatically (they are converted to Parameter Fields in the report).

I'm assuming that you are using a Command object because of the query's complexity.  If you can push the complexity to a SQL view, then use the 'visual linking' expert to create your query, you'll have more flexibility.

Comment: That's a really good idea.  I can use a View to store my complex logic and then add it via CR through linking.  Then CR will pass through the selection formula in the where clause.